# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using resignFirstResponder on textFieldShouldReturn for iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, exc-bad-access, textfield, resignfirstresponder

I have a textfield that i want to hide when the user presses the return button.  the textfield was created in the interface builder, i added the textfield delegate in my .h file, and set the delegate for the textfield as the file owner.

```
@interface ProfileEdit : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>{
    UITextField *textfield1;
    UITextField *textfield2;
    UITextField *textfield3;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
textfield1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 49, 164, 31)];
[textfield1 setDelegate:self];
[textfield1 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[self.view addSubview:textfield1];
textfield2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 124, 164, 31)];
[textfield2 setDelegate:self];
[textfield2 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[self.view addSubview:textfield2] 
textfield3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 198, 164, 31)];
[textfield3 setDelegate:self];
[textfield3 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[self.view addSubview:textfield3];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I also put a button in the background, where the touchupinside event triggers

```
-(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender{
    [textfield1 resignFirstResponder];
    [textfield2 resignFirstResponder];
    [textfield3 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This works fine, no errors.  But for this

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self hideKeyboard:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the main.m.  I've been stuck on this for a couple days and have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Please show any code in which you are creating, releasing or altering the textfields and their delegates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this on my iphone and there was no error.  I think it has to do with the simulator itself.  I found that if i put a delay on the `[testField resignFirstResponder]`, no error is thrown in the simulator

Answer (score 1):

For any EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors, you are usually trying to send a message to a released object. The **BEST** way to track these down is use [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled).

This works by never actually releasing an object, but by wrapping it up as a "zombie" and setting a flag inside it that says it normally would have been released. This way, if you try to access it again, it still know what it was before you made the error, and with this little bit of information, you can usually backtrack to see what the issue was.

It especially helps in background threads when the Debugger sometimes craps out on any useful information.

**VERY IMPORTANT TO NOTE** however, is that you need to 100% make sure this is only in your debug code and not your distribution code. Because nothing is ever released, your app will leak and leak and leak. To remind me to do this, I put this log in my appdelegate:

```
if (getenv("NSZombieEnabled"))
  NSLog(@"NSZombieEnabled enabled!");
```

If you need help finding the exact line, Do a Build-and-Debug (**CMD-Y**) instead of a Build-and-Run (**CMD-R**).  When the app crashes, the debugger will show you exactly which line and in combination with NSZombieEnabled, you should be able to find out exactly why.

Comment: I actually ran this with NSZombieEnabled, NSDebugEnabled, MallocStackLoggin, and MallocStackLoggingNoCompact but it wasn't able to catch the error.  Also, CMD-Y didn't do anything and i couldn't find the build-and-debug option.  I'm running Xcode 4.1

Answer (score 1):

Change return value of textFieldShouldReturn to NO.

I had this problem even without resignFirstResponder call when I was displaying a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-write the `hideKeyboard` method to:

```
- (IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender; {
  if ([textfield1 isFirstResponder]) {
    [textfield1 resignFirstResponder];
  }
  if ([textfield2 isFirstResponder]) {
    [textfield2 resignFirstResponder];
  }
  if ([textfield3 isFirstResponder]) {
    [textfield3 resignFirstResponder];
  }
}
```

Also, make sure that the outlets are all hooked up properly in the nib, and that your file is a `UITextFieldDelegate`, and the textfields should have their delegate hooked up to file owner in the nib. That should (hopefully) fix the problem.

***EDIT:*** You should try putting the 3 `UITextFields` in the nib, and hooking them up that way. It usually results in less problems, and it is easier to change the design later if you need to.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  I tried your solution and checked the delegates, but still no luck.  The if function does work though, so i can confirm that one of the textfields are the first responder.

Comment: Can you post more code? It should be easier to debug the problem if you do.

Comment: `[super viewDidLoad];` should be called first, but other then that, it looks fine. Maybe try eliminating the lines where you set the autocorrection types, just to see if it works without them?

Comment: Also, are you sure you aren't releasing the textfields anywhere other than the dealloc method?

Comment: I commented out the autocorrection types and searched for "release" throughout the .m file and they are not released anywhere else.  Still doesn't work.  I did this through the nib before but changed it to code so you could see what I did.

Comment: It seems like it should be working fine. There doesn't seems to be anything wrong with the code you posted. I would suggest starting a new simple View-based project, and putting in the UITextField related code into the new project, and see if the code works there. If it does, then there is something wrong with some other part of your code.